# How to know and debug the order of thread execution in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, gdb

How to know and debug the order of thread execution in Linux. Tried Gdb, but not helped much?
I connected to target remotely and used gdb, but not sure how to see all the thread execution order. 
Used "info threads" by using gdb but not helped much.
I want to see all the information of process and thread and the order of execution.
I used Htop command but it is not helped me much.

Please let me know if any idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "order of thread execution"? Do you mean which thread is currently executing? Or a snapshot of all the thread PCs. Or??

Comment: Yes, I need to see the list of threads with their priority and to see the the threads are running as per the scheduling process used in our project. I have tried connecting remotely with the gdb and as our target supports only gdbserver.. when i give "info threads" it just giving only one thread information. And distribution is timesys linux.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [systemtap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/). That is a tracing framework that allows you to hook into system and process events such as context switches, function exit and function entry. Relevant for you is [this stap script](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/profiling/sched_switch.stp) which traces scheduler swicthes.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to see ... the order of execution

The order of execution is not defined, and will change from run to run.

If your program is dependent on that order in any way, it's broken, and you should fix it (by adding proper locking and/or synchronization).

If you don't know how to fix it, get a good book on multi-threaded programming.

Comment: The order is depending the scheduler and in my architecture, it is Roundrobin. I am performing the test as per the requirement to see the order and execution as per the priority of the process/threads.